# Create an list and get next value from list until the end of the list in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

How can I create a list in node.js and keep getting the next value from the list until the end of the list?

Comment: there's many ways to do this, depending on how you create the list, and how you *consume* the list. Since it depends on exactly how you are using it - which you've failed to describe - the answer is a pineapple - iterators and generators are two things I'd research

Comment: @Bravo Can you please just show any of the ways ?

Comment: `var array = [1,2,3,4]; array.forEach(item => { /*use the item in some way*/ })`